# Не работает AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

Подскажите в чем проблема, вроде код написал правильно, а AJAX не работает. В чем может быть проблема.(jquery 1.9)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var thisUri = getThisUri()?getThisUri():'index.php';

    history.replaceState({uri:thisUri}, null, thisUri);

$("a[rel~='ajax_load_span8']").click(function(e){

      var uri = $(this).attr('href');

      history.pushState({uri:uri}, null, uri);

      openPage(uri);      
      return false;
 });
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(event) { 
      openPage(history.state.uri);  
    });
        function openPage(uri){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.php",
        data: {
          uri: uri
        },
        cache: false, 
beforeSend : function(){
                $('#receipt-container').fadeIn();
            },      
        success: function(data){  
          $('.span8').html(data);
          $('#receipt-container').fadeOut();
        }
      });
    }
});
```

А вот из чего состоит файл ajax.php

```
 $ajax = true; 
 if(!empty($_POST['uri'])){   include
 $_POST['uri']; }
```

Comment: а как именно не работает ? 

варианты:

 1. синтаксическая ошибка. 
 1. не посылает ничего
 2. посылает не то
 3. приходит не то
 4. приходит то, но success, не срабатывает. 

всё это, и многое другое, можно узнать, воспользовавшись  chrome dev tools или firebug.

Comment: include $_POST['uri'];

![фыв][http://cs9618.vk.me/u62709792/107555753/x_59b28972.jpg]

Comment: @Sh4dow ну будем надеяться, что это просто пример, а не рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите в ajax тип данных, которые получаете в ответе и пробуйте так:

```
if(!empty($_POST['uri'])){
    ob_start();
    include $_POST['uri'];
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $output;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Вроде поменяла, но ошибка в том же, какие есть еще варианты ?

Comment: > но ошибка в том же

Так а в чем ошибка? Скопируйте ее сюда.

P.S. И вообще, что вы пытаетесь подключить?

Comment: Консоль хрома так таковой ошибки и не выдает, в этом и весь нюанс. Почему то не происходит сам ajax запрос мне кажется, я вот только не могу понять почему. Если теоретически все правильно написано. А вообще пытаюсь совместить ajax и изменение url параллельное. манипуляции с историей как в vk, может вы знаете более разумное решение ввиде какого нибудь плагина jquery ?

Comment: Не туда копаетею Начните [с обзора HTML5 History API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/). Есть и [готовые решения](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API) в этом направлении.

Comment: в консоле хрома есть ещё и вкладка network, там есть посылаемые и отправляемые данные.

Comment: http://doduts.comoj.com/ http://doduts.comoj.com/archive.tar.gz